# Binding database data to the GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to bind database data to the gridview in c# and asp.net. But I couldn't see the datas in the gridview.Rows are added to the gridview but they are empty. When I run that query in SQLServer, it gives the correct result.I didn't add or change any code to the asp part.Should I? I couldn't find where is the problem :( please help..

```
myConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KutuphaneConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
connect = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
command = new SqlCommand();
connect.Open();
command.Connection = connect;

 string komut = "SELECT K.ad,K.yazar,K.baskiNo,O.sonTeslimTarihi FROM OduncIslemleri O,Kitap K WHERE O.kullaniciId=" + Session["id"] + " AND O.kitapId = K.id;";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCommand = connect.CreateCommand();
                sqlCommand.CommandText = komut;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand.CommandText, connect);
                SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                //Create a DataTable to hold the query results.
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                //Fill the DataTable.
                sda.Fill(dTable);
                GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

reader.Close();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: You should provide the aspx-part of the GridView. Are you [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)? Besides, remember not to rebind the GridView from Page_Load in Postbacks. So always check for `!Page.IsPostback` before you DataBind the Grid.

Comment: how? could you explain in code samples?

Comment: first complete with the missing aspx-part in your question. And what part would you like to be explained? The GridView-property `AutoGenerateColumns` is selfexplaining, besides i've provided a link. The [postback-check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28VS.71%29.aspx) is also simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the correct answer :

```
myConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KutuphaneConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
connect = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
string sorgu = "select K.ad,K.yazar,K.baskiNo,O.sonTeslimTarihi from Kitap K, OduncIslemleri O where O.kitapId = K.id and O.kullaniciId = "+ Session["id"];
SqlDataAdapter sadp = new SqlDataAdapter(sorgu, connect);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sadp.Fill(ds);
this.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
this.GridView1.DataBind();
connect.Close();
```

I also used template fields in Gridview. Also autogeneratedFields should be true. I hope this helps to the people who have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

watch for another event triggered after the bind that could be clearing the rows

Comment: I don't think so.. I wrote it page_load class and they are te last sentences than page is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a DataSet and populate that using Fill instead.  I've never seen Fill used on a DataTable - and can't find that particular overload on MSDN.  My suspicion is, though, that such an overload would not modify the existing schema of the DataTable (which, since it's only just been created prior to use in your example, would mean that it has no columns).

Comment: I tried this but it gave also same result :

 string komut = "SELECT K.ad,K.yazar,K.baskiNo,O.sonTeslimTarihi FROM OduncIslemleri O,Kitap K WHERE O.kullaniciId=" + Session["id"] + " AND O.kitapId = K.id;";
     
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(komut, connect);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "Kitap");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: How about with `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a BindingSource Control, you set the DataSource of it to the DataTable, and then set the GridView's DataSource to the BindingSource.