# how can i bind the button to data which is coming from db in gridview c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

from the db returns a column's value named RSS_Title and when I  click the it. I want to handle the row index of this value. How can i do it?

I tried some codes but it does not work

```
               <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton2_Click"><%#Eval("RSS_Title")%></asp:LinkButton>

                    </ItemTemplate>

               </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998571/binding-database-data-to-the-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: You can use **GridView.RowUpdating** or **GridView.RowEditing** event to achieve this. Just google it you will find many resources :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the below code in the `LinkButton2_Click` event

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the button that raised the event
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton )sender;

        //Get the row that contains this button
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        //Get rowindex
        int rowindex = gvr.RowIndex;
    }
```

Comment: how can i get value of this column it returns null string a = GridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[6].Text.ToString();

Comment: `((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex`

Comment: ok it gets the row index but i ask how i get the text value of linkbutton

Comment: btn.Text as the sender is the LinkButton